# Problem Uploading CSS File to Seaside FileLibrary

Tags: css, web, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I am a beginner to Seaside and am currently working through the Dynamic Web Development with Seaside book/tutorial.
I'm currently at chapter 17.4, where I need to upload a .png and a .css file to a FileLibrary I created.

I tried uploading them through the Seaside configuration page.  The .png uploaded and is working fine.  However when I tried the .css file, Seaside gave me this: Error: Improper store into indexable object.

I tried uploading the file programmatically as they demonstrated, and it appeared to work at first, but I noticed it was not displaying and the source code didn't show any references to it in the  tag in the browser.
When I investigated the file in Pharo, in the method, it was returning as nil.

If anyone can provide and explanation as to why this isn't working, I would really appreciate it.  I don't know if it will help but here is the stack trace from the error:

```
Stack Trace
thisContext
ByteString(Object)>>error:
self
'...etc...
thisContext
ByteString(Object)>>errorImproperStore
self
'...etc...
thisContext
ByteString>>at:put:
self
'...etc...
thisContext
WriteStream>>nextPut:
self
a WriteStream
thisContext
[ :writeStream | | readStream | readStream := aString readStream. [ readStream atEnd ] whileFalse:...etc...
self
a GRPharoPlatform
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have hit the same problem as described in [this github issue](https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside/issues/1043), but similar stack traces have popped up with earlier versions of Seaside in Pharo 7. So, first make sure you are using the latest stable version of Seaside (see [load instructions for Seaside in Pharo](https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside#install-in-pharo)). Unfortunately, if you load from the Pharo catalog, you are not using the latest stable version.

If you still have the same problem: a `.css` file should have been detected as a text file and the issue is not the same. Please submit the issue to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside/issues/) such that we can reproduce the problem.

In the meantime, I suspect the problem to be in the web tools and you could circumvent the problem by uploading the file programmatically:

`YourLibraryClass addFileAt: 'yourfile.css'`